# Replace string from and including '_' up to excluding ':' script?

Tags: linux, command-line, bash, sed

I am trying to remove a string from and including one char, '_' up to but not including another char, ':'. Everything is on the same line.

I have files with different names and numbers, that contain for example:

```
some_name_123:456(other_name_123:456,some_word_567:765, and so on...
```

I am trying to remove the _123,_567, which is a different pattern after each word, so I end up with:

```
some_name:456(other_name:456,some_word:765,
```

However, I can only seem to remove everything from the first _ to the : which gives some_:456 which isn't what I want. Below is what I have so far. Can anybody help?

```
sed -e 's/\(+\).*\(@\)/\1\2/'
```

This gives what I want on the first occurrence, but not the rest of the occurrences:

```
sed 's/_[^_]\+:/:/'
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the global `g` flag:

```
sed 's/_[^_]\+:/:/g'
```

See: [The s Command](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/html_node/The-_0022s_0022-Command.html).

Comment: thank you this worked!